# O que é o Google One Tap?

Tags: google, identity

Navegando em alguns sites, vi um pop-up dizendo que posso fazer o login utilizando minha conta do google:

[image: Pop-up exibido]

Gostaria saber o que exatamente ele é.

Cheguei até esse [site](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/) porém não tem muitos detalhes do seu funcionamento e de como posso utilizá-lo em minhas aplicações.

Comment: Esses dias tava me perguntando como o Medium fazia isso, "mas como eles sabem dessa minha conta?"

Comment: Exatamente essa pergunta que me fiz, acho que é algúm google ou arquivo igual anunciantes fazem, mas não tinha acho em nenhum lugar os detalhes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De acordo com o site: https://zapier.com/engineering/google-one-tap-inline/

O Google One-tap é uma nova experiência que permite aos usuários criar uma conta ou fazer login no seu site com um único clique. Ele se baseia no popular botão Entrar com o Google para cortar uma página inteira do fluxo de autenticação.

O Google One-tap faz parte da especificação OpenYOLO-Web, que permite que o  injetado do Google em nosso  seja colocado onde desejarmos. Isso permite que o Google One-tap seja uma parte natural de seus designs.

Um exemplo de uma aplicação com esta funcionalidade pode ser encontrada aqui: https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline?

Nesta página: https://medium.com/groww-engineering/all-about-googles-one-tap-sign-in-b8c1c93305d4 existe um passo-a-passo de como proceder:

1. Carregue a biblioteca do cliente googleyolo.

```
<script src="https://smartlock.google.com/client"></script>
```

2. Chame `googleyolo.retrieve()` para verificar se o usuário pode entrar automaticamente.

```js
const retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve({
  supportedAuthMethods: [
    "https://accounts.google.com"
  ],
  supportedIdTokenProviders: [
    {
      uri: "https://accounts.google.com",
      clientId: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    }
  ]
});
```

3. Se a recuperação falhar, chame `googleyolo.hint()` para solicitar que o usuário escolha uma Conta do Google para se inscrever.

```js
/* Check user not already logged in */
if(!hasSession()){
  googleyolo.hint({
    supportedAuthMethods: [
     "https://accounts.google.com"
    ],
    supportedIdTokenProviders: [{
      uri: "https://accounts.google.com",
      clientId: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    }],
    context: "signUp"
  }).then((credential) => {
    /* hit backend api and API TOKEN here */
    /* Also save basic details that we get here */
  }, (error)=> {
    console.log("Error occurred: ",error.type);
  });
}
```

4. No objeto de credencial acima, você obterá o token de ID e outras informações básicas, como displayName, id, profilePicture. Colete os dados e encaminhe-os para o back-end e use-os para criar uma nova conta.

No entanto, lembre-se de que você não pode obter o token de acesso a partir de agora usando a API googleyolo. Use Auth2 em vez disso.

5. Mas aqui está o problema, essa API ainda não está aberta por motivos de segurança. O uso dessa API requer revisão e aprovação. Envie o formulário de solicitação de revisão para iniciar o processo. Todos os passos acima podem ser feitos e colocados em um ramo separado. Depois de obter o acesso à API, tudo está pronto para ser utilizado.

Answer (score 1):

O **Google** tanto como outros provedores de identidade (**Facebook**, **Microsoft**, etc..), permitem que outras aplicações usem o seu registo como *identidade do utilizador*, desta forma as informações utilizadas pela aplicação serão apenas as que o provedor de identidade disponibilizar, normalmente o **email** e o **nome** do utilizador.

Isto permite que o utilizador não precise de se registar em todos os sites digitando os mesmos dados e assim este processo ocorre de maneira mais suave e rápida a nível de interatividade.

Comment: Sim, mas como o site sabe quem eu sou se ainda não fui até a página do provedor e forneci minha credenciais? Como posso usar isso em um site meu? Sei que dá para fornecer esse método de autenticação, inclusive já uso, mas não igual esses sites, eles identificam no primeiro acesso quem eu sou, acho que com base no meu login do navegador

Answer (score 0):

A ideia do **Google One Tap** é bastante simples...

O **Google One Tap** serve para **inscrever** os **usuários** com **um único toque** e **mante-los conectados automaticamente**. Abaixo será demonstrado o funcionamento do **Fluxo de Login e Inscrição Contínua**..

### **Inscrição com um toque**

> Inscreva novos usuários com apenas um toque, sem interrompê-los com uma tela de inscrição. Os usuários recebem uma conta sem senha, segura e baseada em tokens no seu site, protegida por sua Conta do Google.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### **Login automático**

> Faça login dos usuários automaticamente quando eles retornarem ao seu site em qualquer dispositivo ou navegador, mesmo depois que a sessão expirar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como o determinado site sabe quem você é, se você ainda não foi até a página do provedor e forneceu suas credenciais?**

> Esta pergunta é bastante difícil de ser respondida, porém levando em consideração que é da Google e eles dominam o mercado de pesquisa, android entre outros... Provavelmente eles utilizam inteligência artificial, data mining, vasculham o seu cache entre outros métodos "obscuros". Sabe aqueles anúncios que aparece para você ? E você fala, poxa eu estava pensando em comprar isto, ou fazer esta viagem..? Funciona da mesma forma.

**Nota:**

> O programa de teste beta para esta API está atualmente fechado.
>   Estamos aprimorando a funcionalidade de vários navegadores da API e
>   forneceremos atualizações aqui nos próximos meses.

Retirada da [FONTE OFICIAL DA GOOGLE](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)